# Specify platform and vendor in UIWebView on iOS?

Tags: javascript, swift, uiwebview

I found a simple way to change the user agent being sent in a UIWebView by setting the UserDefaults in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.

```
let userAgent = "fake user agent text"

UserDefaults.standard.register(defaults: [
  "UserAgent": userAgent
])
```

But I'd also like to specify the `platform` and `vendor` properties that are exposed in the `navigator` object in the UIWebView context. I've tried adding them as additional defaults, but they don't seem to be set in the `navigator` javascript object for the webview.

```
UserDefaults.standard.register(defaults: [
  "UserAgent": userAgent,
  "platform": "MacIntel",
  "Vendor": "Google Inc"
])
```

Is there a way to do this?